# jQuery to call Action Method in ASP.NET MVC C# by Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have tried for hours to get this working, and I am really hoping one of you knows (a heck of a lot) more about this than I. When the client keys up in a textbox, I would like to call the MVC C# controller method called updateOrder(). Ideally, I would like to access form elements with a FormCollection (the form is called "createOrder").

In the controller, I have:

C#

```
[WebMethod]
public static void updateOrder(){
    string s = "asdf";
}
```

The string declaration above is breakpointed. In the view, I have a method I basically copy and pasted that I found on stackoverflow:

JavaScript

```
function updateOrderJS() {
    var $form = $('form[id="createOrder"]');
    $.ajax({type    : "POST",
        url     : $form.attr('action'),
        data    : $form.serialize(),
        error   : function(xhr, status, error) {},
        success : function(response) {
             updateOrder();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

The event is simply:

JavaScript

```
updateOrderJS();
```

The updateOrderJS() method fires (checked with an alert), but the breakpoint does not.

Comment: Can you debug and see the value you are getting in $form.attr('action')?

Comment: change "type" to "method" in your ajax call e.g. method : "POST" instead of: "type : "POST"

Comment: Check This: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Multiple-ways-to-call-Controller-Action-Method-from-a-Razor-View

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Asp.Net MVC, you do not need to decorate your method with `WebMethod`. You just create an Action (which is a method) and return a result from it. For sample:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller 
{
   public ActionResult Index() 
   {
       return View();
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult UpdateOrder()
   {
      // some code
      return Json(new { success = true, message = "Order updated successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

And in your `View`, you could try a javascript like this (using the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) jquery method -- see the comments):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateOrder")', // to get the right path to controller from TableRoutes of Asp.Net MVC
    dataType: "json", //to work with json format
    type: "POST", //to do a post request 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //define a contentType of your request
    cache: false, //avoid caching results
    data: {}, // here you can pass arguments to your request if you need
    success: function (data) {
         // data is your result from controller
        if (data.success) { 
            alert(data.message);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Felipe, your awesome. I'm sure other answers may have been correct, and I chose yours because it was pretty much plug and play (so-to-write). Now I can start adding the server-side code. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In MVC, you don't need the `[WebMethod]` stuff - you just can have a regular controller action returning an `ActionMethod` (or null if you don't need a return value). The `WebMethod` attribute with static methods is for WebForms, not MVC.

```
public ActionMethod updateOrder(MyModel someModel) {
    // Do something
    return null;
}
```

Your URL in the javascript would be the URL to that action, which you can get to in Razor using `@Url.Action("updateOrder", "Orders")`, where "Orders" is the name of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure "url" is in the format **page.aspx/updateOrder**.
2. Specify `datatype: json`
3. Ensure your `updateOrderJS()` is being called.
4. Ensure `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` is included.

Note: `[WebMethod]` is used for calling webforms methods, not MVC.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you. But I don't think MVC Urls generally include `page.aspx`. The datatype and contentType might affect whether the model binder works, but I'm not sure it'd affect whether the route gets called at all. And the asker already said in his question that he verified that updateOrderJS() was getting called.

Comment: The WebMethodAttribute is used in web forms, as are static methods, therefore I thing there is confusion here. I added a note at the bottom to explain this too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're putting the URL of the MVC route in the `action` attribute of your `<form>` tag. I can't see what that attribute looks like because you didn't post your html, but from what I can see the value of that attribute might be wrong.

Most of the time, the URL to a specific MVC action is `http://ServerDomain/Path(IfAny)/ControllerName/ActionName`. For example, if you have a controller and action like this...

```
public class StackController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Overflow()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

...and your ASP.NET application is deployed to www.example.com, the URL in the `action` attribute of your `<form>` tag would be `http://www.example.com/Stack/Overflow`.

Of course, it's possible for other settings in your ASP.NET MVC to change these URLs, such as the route setup in your global.asax's `RegisterRoutes` method, or perhaps if your controllers are divided into Areas. If the URL of your `<form>` looks correct, please post the html along with any relevant controller routing code in your ASP.NET app.

If your form is inside of a Razor view (cshtml file), you can use `<form action="@Url.Action({ controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName" })" method="post">` to generate the correct form URL.