# ajax code for storing multiple checkbox values to an array and pass to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

Please share the ajax code for storing multiple checkboxes checked values to an array and pass to controller without submit button in MVC4. Please guide me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you looked online yet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

User Jquery Ajax to call your controller's method.

Controller Code :

```
 public class CustomerController : Controller 
 {
  public ActionResult Index() 
  {
   return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult UpdateOrder()
  {
  // some code
  return Json(new { success = true, message = "Order updated successfully"    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
  }
```

Jquery code :

```
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("UpdateOrder")', // to get the right path to controller from TableRoutes of Asp.Net MVC
dataType: "json", //to work with json format
type: "POST", //to do a post request 
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //define a contentType of your request
cache: false, //avoid caching results
data: {}, // here you can pass arguments to your request if you need
success: function (data) {
     // data is your result from controller
    if (data.success) { 
        alert(data.message);
    }
},
error: function (xhr) {
    alert('error');
}
});
```

Above code has taken as reference from here :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/337dfd/useful-way-to-call-controller-actions-from-html-using-jquery/

[jQuery to call Action Method in ASP.NET MVC C# by Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133132/jquery-to-call-action-method-in-asp-net-mvc-c-sharp-by-ajax)

Hope this would help.

Comment: but i cannot find anywhere of sending checked values to controller in your answer @Naresh Parmar

Comment: You have to get the checkbox value using Jquery and pass it in data.